# Extract values from Line Item list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list of 'LI' (specificationItem) items that i need to extract the values of. The values I require are in the

How can i return all the LI values and catch the values ?

```
                <div class="vehicle-features">
                    <h2 class="vehicle-features_header">Specification</h2>

<div class="specificationList">
    <ul class="inner">

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_0" class="odometer">Odometer</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">11,984 miles</span>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_1" class="colourGroup">Colour Group</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">Blue</span>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_2" class="fuelType">Fuel Type</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">Diesel</span>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_3" class="transmission">Transmission</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">Automatic</span>  
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_4" class="bodyStyle">Body Style</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">Hatchback</span>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_5" class="co2">CO2</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">114 g/km</span>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_6" class="milesPerGallon">Miles Per Gallon</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">64.2 mpg</span>         
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>

                <li class="specificationItem">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="icon">
                            <span id="Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_8" class="trimColour">Trim Colour</span>                                
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="value">
                        <span class="valueContent">black cloth</span>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </li>
    </ul>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What values to be exact? All? Like... `Odometer`, `11,984 miles`? Repeat for all `<li>`?

Comment: the values i need to retreive in the above sample are : 
11,984 miles , 
Blue , 
Diesel ,
Automatic , 
Hatchback ,
64.2 mpg ,
black cloth ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all the *specificationItem* and the respective *values* you can use the following code block :

```
List<String> specificationItems = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> specificationValues = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> all_specificationItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='specificationList']/ul[@class='inner']//li[@class='specificationItem']/dl/dt[@class='icon']/span[starts-with(@id,'Body_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_VehicleFeatures_FeatureList_FeatureText_')]"));
List<WebElement> all_specificationValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='specificationList']/ul[@class='inner']//li[@class='specificationItem']/dl//span[@class='valueContent']"));
int size = all_specificationItems.size();
for(WebElement ele:all_specificationItems)
    specificationItems.add(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for(WebElement elem:all_specificationValues)
    specificationValues.add(elem.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    System.out.println(specificationItems.get(i) + " has a value of " + specificationValues.get(i));
```

Comment: Excellent solution .. 
Will be saving that in the knowledge bank ... Thanks

Comment: That Xpath solution is way too brittle imho

Answer (score 0):

When you use a css selector based on a classname and there is more than one element, a list of elements will be returned. Once you have this list, you can iterate over it and retrieve the values. Like so:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".specificationItem"));
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    WebElement value = element.findElements(By.cssSelector(".valueContent"));
    System.out.println(value.getText());
}
```

Above code will iterate over all the webelements with classname *specificationItem* and extract each webelement with classname *valueContent*. Then it will print the inner text of the item.

If you don't care about the li-elements, you don't have to iterate over the li-elements and you can do the following:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".valueContent"));
elements.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: the first snippet would do what i need , but is returning a mismatch on :      WebElement value = element.findElements(By.cssSelector(".valueContent"));